# Problem with binary tree & depth first search

Tags: c, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I need to find the sum of the values ​​of its deepest leaves. This code works but not correctly.

```
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 */
int sum = 0;
void  dfs(struct TreeNode *root, int lvl){
    if(root == NULL) return ;
    int maxlvl = -1;
    if(lvl > maxlvl){
        maxlvl = lvl;
        sum = root->val;
    }
    else if (lvl == maxlvl){
        sum += root->val;
    }
    dfs(root->left, lvl+1);
    dfs(root->right, lvl+1);
}
int deepestLeavesSum(struct TreeNode* root){
    dfs(root,0);
    return sum;
}
```

I suspect that the error is that I do not transfer the sum and declare it globally. But I don't really understand how to pass it to me and what I should put in the function.

Comment: `int maxlvl = -1;` followed by `if(lvl > maxlvl){` will *never* hit the `else if` branch.

Comment: I think `maxlvl` needs to be a global. And you need `sum = 0;` and `maxlvl = -1;` at the beginning of the `deepestLeavesSum` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this code. First of all, maxlvl is always either -1 or the current level, so the else if never gets reached and instead sum is made equal to the last node that was visited. I assume that maxlvl is the deepest you want to search in the tree, so I would make it a global variable with a constant value.

Furthermore, you are supposed to sum the deepest leaves, yet there is no check to see if you have actually reached a leaf.

I will assume you also have to sum the values in nodes at the deepest search layer, and suggest this edit:

```
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 */

int sum = 0;
int maxlvl = 10;

void dfs(struct TreeNode *root, int lvl){
    if(root == NULL) return;

    if (lvl == maxlvl || !(root->left || root->right)){
        sum += root->val;
        return;
    }

    dfs(root->left, lvl+1);
    dfs(root->right, lvl+1);
}

int deepestLeavesSum(struct TreeNode* root){
    dfs(root,0);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: So I really don't know maxlvl. Therefore, this code is not working.

Comment: @ДенисМороз It was your code that introduced the concept of a `maxlvl`. If you don't have a maximum depth to care about, just remove the test for `lvl == maxlvl`. A leaf node is one without any children, which is what the posted answer is testing for, and which your original code didn't test.

Comment: @ДенисМороз if you need maxlvl to be the highest depth reached, place `maxlvl = -1` outside of the function, remove `lvl == maxlvl` from the conditional and add the conditional `if (lvl > maxlvl) maxlvl = lvl` above the former.

Comment: @pmacfarlane First sentence from the question: *"I need to find the sum of the values ​​of its deepest leaves."* That's **deepest leaves**, not **all leaves**. The code in this answer computes the sum of leaves at some arbitrarily chosen depth. That is completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: @user3386109 Ah... ok, got it. My bad. And now the code in the question makes a bit more sense. You should make an answer from your comment to the OP. I think you're right.